# Rescore Items from Scoring Key

Tags: r, plyr, scoring

I have a set of data on which respondents were given a series of questions, each with five response options (e.g., 1:5).  Given those five options, I have a scoring key for each question, where some responses are worth full points (e.g., 2), others half points (1), and others no points (0).  So, the data frame is n (people) x k (questions), and the scoring key is a k (questions) x m (responses) matrix.

What I am trying to do is to programmatically create a new dataset of the rescored items.  Trivial dataset:

```
x <- sample(c(1:5), 50, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(c(1:5), 50, replace = TRUE)
z <- sample(c(1:5), 50, replace = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,z)) # 3 items, 50 observations (5 options per item)
head(dat)
  x y z
1 3 1 2
2 2 1 3
3 5 3 4
4 1 4 5
5 1 3 4
6 4 5 4

# Each option is scored 0, 1, or 2:
key <- matrix(sample(c(0,0,1,1,2), size = 15, replace = TRUE), ncol=5)
key
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    2
[2,]    2    1    1    1    2
[3,]    2    2    1    1    2
```

Comment: Why are you using `data.frame(cbind(.))` and not just `data.frame(.)`. The former is bad practice, especially if the vectors being bound are different types.

Comment: Good point!  cbind() was unnecessary here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some other options, firstly using `Map`:

```
data.frame(Map( function(x,y)  key[y,x], dat, seq_along(dat) ))

#  x y z
#1 0 2 2
#2 0 2 1
#3 2 1 1
#4 0 1 2
#5 0 1 1
#6 1 2 1
```

Secondly using matrix indexing on `key`:

```
newdat <- dat
newdat[] <- key[cbind( as.vector(col(dat)), unlist(dat) )]
newdat

#  x y z
#1 0 2 2
#2 0 2 1
#3 2 1 1
#4 0 1 2
#5 0 1 1
#6 1 2 1
```

Things would be even simpler if you specified `key` as a `list`:

```
key <- list(x=c(0,0,0,1,2),y=c(2,1,1,1,2),z=c(2,2,1,1,2))
data.frame(Map("[",key,dat))

#  x y z
#1 0 2 2
#2 0 2 1
#3 2 1 1
#4 0 1 2
#5 0 1 1
#6 1 2 1
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but in general, how is the scoring key determined?

Comment: @RichardScriven - it's not specified clearly. Each row of `key` is a question and each column is the response (1-5). The returned value is the content of the cell.

Comment: Yes, in this example I just randomly generated the key (second part of the code in the question). In reality, the key will be based upon expert scoring agreement (with >50% of experts agreeing on an option getting a value of 2, with 5-49% of experts agreeing getting a value of 1, and options endorsed less than 5% of the time getting a value of 0).  This will then be used in a partial credit graded response model via mirt.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I was discussing this issue with a friend, who suggested another approach.  The benefits of this is that it still uses mapvalues() to do the rescoring, but does not require a for loop, instead uses "from" in `sapply` to do the indexing.

```
library(plyr)
scored <- sapply(1:ncol(raw), function(x, dat, key){
  mapvalues(dat[,x], from = 1:ncol(key), to = key[x,])    
}, dat = dat, key = key)
```

Comment: Technically, `sapply` is a `for` loop--just slightly optimized :-)

Answer (score 0):

My current working approach is to use 1) `mapvalues`, which lives within `package:plyr` to do the heavy lifting: it takes a vector of data to modify, and two additional parameters "from", which is the original data (here 1:5), and "to", or what we want to convert the data to; and, 2) A `for` loop with index notation, in which we cycle through the available questions, extract the vector pertaining to each using the current loop value, and use it to select the proper row from our scoring key.

```
library(plyr)
newdat <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=nrow(dat), ncol=ncol(dat))
for (i in 1:3) {
    newdat[,i] <- mapvalues(dat[,i], from = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                            to = c(key[i,1], key[i,2], key[i,3], key[i,4], key[i,5]))
}
head(newdat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    2
[2,]    0    2    1
[3,]    2    1    1
[4,]    0    1    2
[5,]    0    1    1
[6,]    1    2    1
```

I am pretty happy with this solution, but if anyone has any better approaches, I would love to see them!